# I can't install Thunderbird

Tags: software-installation, thunderbird

I cannot install thunderbird.tar.bz2. After I extract the file the `make` command does not work. This error appears:

```
$ sudo make
KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/XXXXX/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
/home/XXXXX/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_attach’:
/home/XXXXX/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:485:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_MUTEX’
make[2]: *** [/home/XXXXX/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/XXXXX] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you first try installing from Software Center?

Comment: @Chakra no i didn't.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter to anyone now, but the problem was you were trying to compile (`make`) a binary package. Tar-files, here a tar-bzip2 file, can be used for source code (and often are, though usually tar.gz/tgz which are both tar-gzip) but can also be used for already compiled binaries. You only needed to extract the package and then run ./thundebird/thunderbird from the folder you extracted it into.

Answer (score 17):

Why install the tar version of Thunderbird?

Thunderbird is available in [Ubuntu Software Center](http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/features/ubuntu-software-centre):

[image: tbird]

This is the best version for Ubuntu and has been tested by many many users before you.

EDIT If you want bleeding edge: [Thunderbird 5 hits beta](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/5.0b1/releasenotes/) and a PPA has been provided for Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10 and 11.04.

Highlights:

1. New Addons Manager and extension management API (user interface will be changed before final release)
2. Tabs can now be reordered and dragged to different windows
3. Revised account creation wizard, offering improved set-up
4. Attachment sizes now displayed along with attachments
5. New troubleshooting information page to aid supporting and diagnosing problems in Thunderbird
6. Plugins can now be loaded in RSS feeds by default

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

<sub>As should be expected when using development releases, be aware that some extensions installed in earlier builds of Thunderbird may be incompatible and/or require updates to work with Thunderbird Beta.</sub>

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: @real if the answer suits you best please tag the green button :)